# How can I Count, group and show age from my database

Tags: laravel, date, calculator, laravel-blade

I have a table organigrammes with 100 records. And in this table organigrammes i have 4 columns:

- id
- name
- date_birth
- date_entry

My Controller here:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $listCollaborateurs = Organigramme::all();

    foreach ($listCollaborateurs as $collaborateur) {

        $now = Carbon::now();
        $date_birth = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $collaborateur->date_birth);
        $age = $now->diffInYears($date_birth);

        $Number1 = age
        ->where(age between 1 and 10)
        ->count();

        $Number2 = age
        ->where(age between 11 and 20)
        ->count();

       return view('home',['Number1' => $Number1, 'Number2' => $Number2]);

    }
```

Now I want to count, group and show in my blade all the records where age is between [1 - 10], [11 - 20]

I need help please!

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this  like:
In your Organigramme Model class write a function that returns age attribute.  Like :

```
protected $appends = ['age'];

public function getAgeAttribute(){
    $now = Carbon::now();
        $date_birth = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->date_birth);
       return  $now->diffInYears($date_birth);
}
```

In your controller :

```
$listCollaborateurs = Organigramme::all();
$number1 =$listCollaborateurs->whereBetween('age',[1,10])->count() ;
$number2 = $listCollaborateurs->whereBetween('age',[11,20])->count();
```

Let me now if it works or not

Comment: Hello @Azahar Alam I try your proposition but I have this error message: InvalidArgumentException
Trailing data

Comment: Finally It's working. I have changed the date format to d-m-Y: Now the solution is:

Comment: public function getAgeAttribute()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $date_birth= Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $this->date_birth);
        return  $now->diffInYears($date_birth);
    }

Comment: Thanks to all for the help